# cakephp2 HABTM relation not displaying duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have HABTM relation of products and orders i have set `unique=false` in both the Model so there can be a duplicate records and also created a table orders_products like **product_id | order_id** , I want to check total ordes for the product my problem is , there is duplicate records in table but it is not displaying. here is my Product controller code

```
$this->Product->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Product.id'=>$id)));
```

Comment: as the name suggests, find('first',…) only gives you the first record matching the conditions, not multiple

Comment: Thanks @DemoUser but I need a order list of particular product (orders_products) so i used 'first'

Comment: But, what do yo need? the first element or list?